# boost thread destroys polymorphism

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

duplicate of: ["pure virtual method called" when implementing a boost::thread wrapper interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160403/pure-virtual-method-called-when-implementing-a-boostthread-wrapper-interface)

I am trying to create a more object oriented version of the threads using boost threads.

So I created a Thread class:

```
class Thread {
public:
    Thread() {}
    virtual ~Thread() { thisThread->join(); }

    void start() { thisThread = new boost::thread(&Thread::run, this); }

    virtual void run() {};

private:
    boost::thread *thisThread;
};
```

this class creates the thread in start()
like this:

`thisThread = new boost::thread(&Thread::run, this);`

The problem is that when I create a class that overwrites the `run()` method, the `run()` method from Thread is call by the thread instead of the new `run()` method

for example I have a class that extends Thread:

```
class CmdWorker: public Thread {
public:
    CmdWorker() : Thread() {}
    virtual ~CmdWorker() {}

    void run() { /* deosn't get called by the thread */ }
};
```

when I do

```
Thread *thread = new CmdWorker();
thread.start(); //---> calls run() from Thread instead of run() from CmdWorker
```

but just to be more clear:

```
thread.run();  calls the correct run from CmdWorker, (run() is virtual from Runnable)
```

Any idea why this happens or how it can be fixed ?

NOTE:
I created a function (that has nothing to do with the Thread class)

```
void callRun(Thread* thread) {
    thread->run();
}
```

and changed the thread creation to:

```
thisThread = new boost::thread(callRun, this);
```

when debugging I noticed that the `thread` pointer is pointing to a object of type Thread instead of CmdWorker

EDIT:

testcase code at: http://ideone.com/fqMLF
and http://ideone.com/Tmva1

Object seems to be sliced (but this is strange since pointers are used)

didn't manage to add boost to it

Comment: The question is unclear to me!

Comment: Not enough code. I fail to see how you would use such construct.

Comment: FYI `std::thread` is arriving. What exactly is wrong with `boost::thread` anyway?

Comment: Should `run()` be virtual in Thread?

Comment: I added more code to make it clear what happens

Comment: try to remove the declaration of `run` from `Thread` and see where you have a "cannot instantiate abstract class blah blah".

Comment: Do you happen to call `start` in the constructor ?

Comment: @Alexandre C: no I do not call start() in the constructor,
and when I remove the run declaration It just crashes
pure virtual call error

Comment: @Hallowed: Okay. Can you post a minimal complete compilable example of the behavior you observe, for instance at http://www.ideone.com (they have boost::thread IIRC) ?

Comment: @Alexandre C: can I compile it there since I use boost ?

Comment: @Hallowed: yes, there is some boost support at ideone. The problem is likely to be not in the code you shown. Either the `Thread` object got sliced somewhere, or the constructor is (indirectly) calling `start`. The fact that the program crashes (with something in the output like "pure virtual function called") when you remove `run` from `Thread` indicates this.

Comment: @Alexandre C: I've added some test code, and it seems that object is sliced

Comment: @Hallowed: Ok, I managed to get it compile on my machine, and surprisingly, I observe your behavior. Let me get to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is in that question:

["pure virtual method called" when implementing a boost::thread wrapper interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3160403/pure-virtual-method-called-when-implementing-a-boostthread-wrapper-interface)

Basically, when the boost::thread object begins running, the object it was run against had the 
time to be deleted.

You have to implement a `join` method that you call manually before destroying the object.

Answer (score 2):

> when debugging I noticed that the thread pointer is pointing to a
>   object of type Thread instead of CmdWorker

Maybe the `CmdWorker` object is sliced (i.e. copied by value) into a `Thread` object somewhere in your code?

Do you get the same behaviour with a minimal test case?

Answer (score 1):

By doing `&Thread::Run` on a non-virtual function, you are forcing any class that derives from Thread to use the function specified in the Thread base class. Try making Thread::Run a virtual void and see if that fixes your issue.

Comment: @Michael : In C++, `virtual` is inherited from the base class as long as the member function signatures match (which they do in this case); declaring `Thread::run` as `virtual` would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

From reading your updates, you're calling delete in the main thread, while the thread is starting in the other.  Depending on the race between the destructor and the invocation of `run`, it will either:

1. Crash before it starts, because the vtable is completely destroyed
2. Call the Thread::run (which is pure virtual, and crashes with a pure virtual thunk)
3. Call the correct function, which is the derived class run()

If you add a call to `sleep(1)` after you call start, but before you call `delete`, you'll find that it works as you expect.

Comment: I simplified the example and removed any locks + checks. 

also in the destructor I do a join() so it waits for the thread to finish.

as I mentioned before the run() from thread is called.

Comment: @Ha11owed If you add a join in the destructor of `Thread`, then by the time join is called, the most derived class has already been destroyed, and the vtable entries for it no longer exist.

Comment: I understand now
didn't notice that